# Как при нажатии на один блок изменился рисунок другого блока? Можно такое только на CSS сделать?

Tags: html, css

Вопрос.

У меня есть 2 блока.

1-й типа включатель.
2-й типа экран.

Смысл такой.

Есть 2 блока DIV с ckass=" и т.д.

Придумал такую штуку, как хочу типа один блок - это экран телевизора, а второй - это кнопка включения.

Нажимаешь на 1-й блок, а на втором изображение из одного меняется на другое.

Как это можно сделать на css?

Или вообще как такое можно сделать?

Я не профи, поэтому, если можно, расскажите без замудреных фраз...

Спасибо.

Comment: slider or tab

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/primer-slaydera-upravlyaemogo-tolko-s-pomoshchyu-css3
http://imperacms.ru/examples/css-slider/index.html

Comment: Только проверяем стили здесь: http://caniuse.com, чтобы потом не удивиться, что ничего не работает в 90% браузеров (сожаление)

Comment: Это-то да... но там нет описания кода ни html, ни css, что и как делать...

А так, да, это почти то, что мне надо, вот толко бы написали, какой код куда прописывать...

Comment: Вроде бы разобрался.

Я прсто сохранил страницу и открыл редактором и в ней был css код.

Comment: @Yuriisk вот тут работающие примеры: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/prevnext.php

Answer (score 1):

На css вашу задумку вряд ли можно реализовать.

Подобное легко и чаще всего наиболее оптимально делать с помощью javascript/jquery.

Comment: Набор скрытых радиобаттонов + набор лейблов + сам див телевизора, все на одном уровне вложенности

Каждый лейбл связан со своим радиобаттоном, показывается только лейбл для радиобаттона, идущего за выбранным (для первого радиобаттона, если выбран последний)

Для каждого выбранного радиобаттона свой фон следующего за ним дива. Переключение за счет нажатий на лейблы. Должно работать на css 2.

Вот и все.

Comment: @Etki

 Согласитесь, что лучше посоветовать человеку выучить js, нежели приводить различные костыли, которые он потом будет пытаться реализовать, впустую тратя время.

Если следовать четко вопросу, то ваш комментарий можно рассматривать, если принять во внимание знания автора вопроса, то лучше посоветовать более оптимальные и верные варианты.

Comment: @mJeevas дали бы тогда ссылку на плагин слайдера на jquery